# useEffect function not called after updating state of a 2d array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a 2d array state full of objects rendered like this:

```
<div id="pieces">
     {
     //pieces of the board
     pieces.map(pieceRow => {
         return pieceRow.map(piece => {
             return piece && <Piece key={piece.id} piece={piece}/>
         })
     })
     }
</div>
```

The useEffect function is in the Piece Component:

```
function Piece({piece}){
    const pieceRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        //this's the useEffect function, where piece is the obj of the 2d array passed by props to the component
        ...
    }, [piece])

    return ...
```

When i update the state moving an element from a row to another row the useEffect is called:

```
newPieces[3][0] = null;
newPieces[4][0] = obj;
[obj.x, obj.y] = [4, 0]
setPieces(newPieces);
```

This piece of code works, but if i try to move the element to another position in the same row the useEffect isn't called (but the state is updated).

This setPieces doesn't call the useEffect:

```
newPieces[3][0] = null;
newPieces[3][1] = obj;
[obj.x, obj.y] = [3, 1]
setPieces(newPieces);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your newPieces is number of multi array only?

Comment: what do you mean ? newPieces is a shallow copy of pieces.

Comment: It isn't, use lodash shalow copy function .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the id of the piece is the same. So React do not re-render the component. Try to include the row in the key. This way the component will re-render when the piece is moved inside its own row.

```js
  pieces.map(pieceRow => {
         return pieceRow.map( (piece,index) => {
             const key = `${piece.id}-row-${index}`;
             return piece && <Piece key={key} piece={piece}/>
         })
     })
``
```

Comment: Tried but didn't work, newPieces is already a new reference to the pieces array.

Comment: Removing the key solve the problem, but what should i do now

Comment: Thank you Erik this definitely solved the problem.